# Does the Trophy Shop always sell unique trophies?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In "Games & More" > "Vault" > "Trophies" > "Shop" Smash for Wii U contains a shop where you can select from one of eight trophies to buy. This selection of eight is different almost every time you load up the shop.

However, what I'm worried about is buying a duplicate trophy. **Does the Shop only ever stock trophies you don't already have?** I don't want to accidentally spend a whole ton of money on a trophy I already have, and I also don't want to have to go all the way to my Trophy list in the Vault and check every time before I buy a trophy from the shop. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, the trophy shop will start selling duplicate trophies. But you don't have to go and check to avoid buying them - they'll have a blue "Unlocked" tag on them.

[image: Trophy Shop with "Unlocked" tags]

- [Information Source](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Trophy_shop)
- [Image Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Astu6uRlnJI)

Comment: Is there any benefit to buying a duplicate trophy?

Comment: If there is, that would be great because I have loads of them from playing Classic mode. Also, this answer is perfect! I had looked on the Smash Wiki before asking but for some reason I didn't think to check if they had a page for the Trophy Shop! Doy!